# draw lines between different plot areas in pgfplots/TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I want to connect the dashed lines precisely to the top corners of the dashed rectangle in the lower plot by using coordinates of the lower plot, such that when the rectangular box is moved, the dashed connections move accordingly. In the example below, the dashed lines would be moved manually, which is too much work...

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{width=1\textwidth,compat=1.9}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[%
    name = plot1, 
    width = 0.3\textwidth, height = 0.3\textwidth,
    xtick pos=top, ytick pos=left,
]
\end{axis}%
%
\begin{axis}[%
    name = plot2,
    at = {($(plot1.south west)+(0.0cm,-0.2cm)$)}, anchor=north west,
    width = 0.5\textwidth, height = 0.5\textwidth,
    xmin=0, xmax=40, ymin=0, ymax=40,
    ]
\addplot coordinates{(10,10)}   ;
% draw rectangle around data
\draw[dashed] (axis cs: 8, 8) rectangle (axis cs: 12, 12);
\end{axis}
%
% draw line to top left corner of rectangle
\draw[dashed] (plot1.south west) --   ($(plot2.south west)+(0.8,1.2)$);
% draw line to to top right corner of rectangle
\draw[dashed] (plot1.south east) --   ($(plot2.south west)+(1.2,1.2)$);
%
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome! Which rectangle gets moved? I don't know if `spy` works with `pgfplots`?

Answer (score 1):

Found an answer, the rectangle needs to be defined as a node, such that its anchors can be used.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{width=1\textwidth,compat=1.9}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[%
    name = plot1, 
    width = 0.3\textwidth, height = 0.3\textwidth,
    xtick pos=top, ytick pos=left,
]
\end{axis}%
%
\begin{axis}[%
    name = plot2,
    at = {($(plot1.south west)+(0.0cm,-0.2cm)$)}, anchor=north west,
    width = 0.5\textwidth, height = 0.5\textwidth,
    xmin=0, xmax=40, ymin=0, ymax=40,
    ]
\addplot coordinates{(10,10)}   ;
% draw rectangle around data
\node[rectangle,draw=black, dashed, minimum width = 0.5cm, minimum height = 0.5cm] (rect) at (axis cs: 10, 10) {};
%
\end{axis}
%
% draw line to top left corner of rectangle
\draw[dashed] (plot1.south west) --   ($(rect.north west)$);
%
% draw line to to top right corner of rectangle
\draw[dashed] (plot1.south east) --   ($(rect.north east)$);
%
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]